# Rendering arrow paths in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, style

I made a map in QGIS, and I now want to render it into a web interactive product. I've tried to use Leaflet but I'm not able to reproduce the same pathways.

So far, I managed to produce simple lines as per code below:

```
        map.createPane('pane_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13');
        map.getPane('pane_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13').style.zIndex = 413;
        map.getPane('pane_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13 = new L.geoJson(json_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: false,
            dataVar: 'json_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13',
            layerName: 'layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13',
            pane: 'pane_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13',
            onEachFeature: pop_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13,
            // style: style_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13);
```

I tried:

```
        var polyline = L.polyline(layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13, {}).addTo(map);
        var arrowHead = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
            patterns: [
                {offset: '100%', repeat: 0, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 60, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}})}
            ]
        }).addTo(map);
```

And this doesn't work.

Example of what I would like to get in figure below (bot the red arrows and the arrow-shaped pathways).

[image: Pathways example to be reproduced in leaflet]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Hello,

Here's an example using [Leaflet.PolylineDecorator](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) : [https://jsfiddle.net/v9asz1gh/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/v9asz1gh/1/)
I don't see anything wrong in your code but maybe the data is not correctly loaded in the first place. Do you at least see the line without the decorations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong in your code is that your are giving layer object as parameter to polyline creation method `L.polyline`. It has to be an array of coordinates. You can get those coordinates from each feature of GeoJSON layer.

But to make it work with Leaflet.PolylineDecorator plugin, you don't add GeoJSON layer to map. You just use this layer to iterate through layers (polylines), create individual polylines with `L.polyline` method and then add decoration with `L.polylineDecorator` method. Best practice would be to add each polyline to group layer and at last add group layer to map.

So the code could look something like this:

```
var layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13 = L.layerGroup({
  attribution: '',
  interactive: false,
  layerName: 'layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13',
  pane: 'pane_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13',
});

function pop_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13(feature, layer) {
  var polyline = L.polyline(layer.getLatLngs()).addTo(layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13);
  var arrowHead = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
    patterns: [
      {offset: '100%', repeat: 0, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 60, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}})}
    ]
  }).addTo(layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13);
  // your code
}

L.geoJson(json_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13, {
  onEachFeature: pop_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13
});

layer_Onthogenetic_Juveniles_Migration_13.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi TomazicM, thanks for that. When I run your code I get an error: "L.groupLayer is not a function". Any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I had too much or not enough coffe. It should be `L.layerGroup` of course. Corrected.

Comment: Oh yes! :) It works now! Thanks again!

Comment: If it helped you to solve your problem, it would be appropriate to accept the answer.